# Batch: Using the find command when path contains wildcards

Tags: batch-file

I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
%~dp0 > %USER% > %DATE1%_%USER%.csv
```

where I am using `SET /P` to create the `USER` & `DATE1` variables.

I have a few queries set up to count the number of lines in the .csv files:

```
:QUERY0
ECHO Searching for %USER% on %DATE1% . . .
FIND /C /V "" "%~dp0%USER%\%DATE1%_%USER%.csv" >> "%~dp0%DATE1%_%USER%_Report.txt" && (ECHO. & ECHO %DATE1%_%USER%_Report.txt Created)
"%~dp0%DATE1%_%USER%_Report.txt"
EXIT

:QUERY1
ECHO Searching for  + ANY USER +  on %DATE1% . . .
FIND /C /V "" "%~dp0*\%DATE1%_*.csv" >> "%~dp0%DATE1%_Report.txt" && (ECHO. & ECHO %DATE1%_Report.txt Created)
"%~dp0%DATE1%_Report.txt"
EXIT

:QUERY2
ECHO Searching for %USER% on  + ANY DATE + . . .
FIND /C /V "" "%~dp0%USER%\*_%USER%.csv" >> "%~dp0%USER%_Report.txt" && (ECHO. & ECHO %USER%_Report.txt Created)
"%~dp0%USER%_Report.txt"
EXIT
```

Queries "0" and "2" work like a dream, but I cannot figure out how to get "1" to work. Is there a way to get `FIND` to use a path with wildcards in it?

Comment: `find` in windows batch locates strings within files. You appear to be using a *nix emulator to find files.

Comment: Wildcards can only be used in the *last* element of a path…

Comment: I have not had success yet, but can I use ```DIR "%~dp0" /A:D /B > "%~dp0Userlist.txt" ``` to get the "Users" and use this text document as an input for ```FIND /C /V "" "%~dp0 <Userlist.txt> \%DATE1%_*.csv" ``` in the <Userlist.txt> section?

Comment: Please remove the `cygwin` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution. It may not be the most elegant, but it works for this scenario.

```
:QUERY1
ECHO Searching for  + ANY USER +  on %DATE1% . . .
IF EXIST "%~dp0Userlist.txt" (DEL "%~dp0Userlist.txt")
DIR "%~DP0" /A:D /B > "%~dp0Userlist.txt"
FOR /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%~dp0Userlist.txt") do (FIND /C /V "" "%~dp0%%L\%DATE1%_%%L.csv" >> "%~dp0_Reports\%DATE1%_Report.txt")
IF EXIST "%~dp0Userlist.txt" (DEL "%~dp0Userlist.txt")
"%~dp0_Reports\%DATE1%_Report.txt"
EXIT
```

I am using the `DIR` to create a list of all of the folders in `%~dp0` which is the usernames I am looking for, and then using some code I borrowed from a different source to read the `.txt` file output of `DIR` with the `FOR` command so that I can assign the lines in the `.txt` file to an arbitrary `%%L` variable to use in the file path.